# My for loop is exiting without completing every number in a list

Tags: python

This is my code, I'm accessing a file called pollution.txt and I'm trying to find the average of all the numbers in each line then displaying it.

```
def month_average(monthlist):
    monthlist = open("pollution.txt", 'r')
    file = monthlist.readlines()
    print("The monthly averages are as follows:")
    for line in file:
        eachline = list(line.split(","))
        count = 0
        sum_all = 0
        average = []
        for x in eachline:
            number = int(x)
            count = count + 1
            sum_all = sum_all + number
            avg = sum_all / count
        average.append(round(avg, 1))
    return average

the_average = month_average("pollution.txt")
print(the_average)
```

This is a small part from the pollution.txt

```
132,142,154,151,143,164,158,150,146,78,141,32,141,142,112,113,116,123,123,119,152,123,127,163,142,85,88,151,142,113,114
89,78,67,65,56,98,123,144,179,86,82,90,172,124,156,187,122,154,144,165,87,152,93,157,134,87,167,98,156,145,133
45,73,167,165,122,148,125,128,75,123,182,144,143,33,122,147,122,178,144,138,87,152,93,57,134,87,67,98
67,54,83,45,56,98,92,121,153,115,98,80,59,63,84,121,144,119,103,97,83,75,56,64,81,99,102,114,116,103,97
```

Comment: Right off the bat it's weird the file name occurs twice. I suggest you eliminate it, and just hard-code the data in your example, then tell us what you get and what you expected.  You pass in the file name monthlist then overwrite it with a file object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're re-assigning `average` on each for loop.

Corrected code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def month_average(monthlist):
    monthlist = open("pollution.txt", 'r')
    file = monthlist.readlines()
    average = []  # initialize once only
    print("The monthly averages are as follows:")
    for line in file:
        eachline = list(line.split(","))
        count = 0
        sum_all = 0
        # average = []  # mistake is here
        for x in eachline:
            number = int(x)
            count = count + 1
            sum_all = sum_all + number
            avg = sum_all / count
        average.append(round(avg, 1))
    return average

the_average = month_average("pollution.txt")
print(the_average)
```

Output:

```
The monthly averages are as follows:
[128.4, 122.3, 117.8, 91.7]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would be better to use "with as" construction for working with an i/o file.
Second list comprehension will be more readable in my opinion.

As a result, code can be rewritten:

```
def average_by_line(line):
    data_array = list(map(int, line.split(",")))
    return sum(data_array) / len(data_array)


def month_average(monthlist):
    with open("pollution.txt", 'r') as monthlist:
        file = monthlist.readlines()
        averages = [average_by_line(line) for line in file]
    return averages

the_average = month_average("pollution.txt")
print(the_average)
```

Answer (score 0):

SIMPle implementation

```
def month_average(file_obj):
    average = []
    with open(file_obj) as fp:
        lines = fp.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip().split(',')
            temp = 0
            for item in line:
                temp += int(item)
            average.append(temp/len(line))
    return average

reqdAvg = month_average("pollution.txt")
print(reqdAvg)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is going to have comma separated values then you can use the csv module. Anyway if you are passing the filename to the function then you should use that rather than explicitly writing the file name again.

```
import csv

def month_average(monthlist):
    with open(monthlist, newline="") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")
        averages = [round(sum(map(int,line))/len(line)) for line in reader]
        return averages

the_average = month_average("pollution.txt")
print(the_average)
```